# calculating the address of global offset table in arm literal pool

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I am trying to understand the arm assembly code for writing the Literal Pool and Global OFFSET table

Compiling the C code with GNU ARM GCC

```
extern int i;
int foo(int j)
{
int t = i;
i = j;
return t;
}
```

GCC generates following code:

```
foo:
    ldr     r3, .L2        
    ldr     r2, .L2+4      
.LPIC0:
    add     r3, pc         
    ldr     r3, [r3, r2]   
    @ sp needed for prologue
    ldr     r2, [r3]
    str     r0, [r3]
    mov     r0, r2
    bx      lr

.L3:
    .align  2

.L2:
    .word   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_-(.LPIC0+4)  
    .word   i(GOT)
```

I want to  manually handle the global offset table in arm assembly.
Now I am facing difficulty to understand the above code.
Can any one please describe the literal pool calculation following lines of code?

```
.L2:
    .word   _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_-(.LPIC0+4) 
    .word   i(GOT)
```

Comment: Please define what you mean with "handling the global offset table". The line you're puzzled about resolves to the offset of `.LPIC0` from the global offset table. This is needed for certain PIC functionality.

Comment: @FUZxxl I want to get GOT[0] which is refer as _DYNAMIC in aarch64

Answer (score 1):

When compiled to a PIC(position independet code) file, global variable need to be relocated.

```
foo:
    ldr     r3, .L2        
    ldr     r2, .L2+4      
.LPIC0:
    add     r3, pc         
    ldr     r3, [r3, r2]
```

Notice `add    r3, pc`, in this instruction, `pc` is `.LPIC0+4`, so the result of `add` is `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_`, which is the entry of the `GOT`.
`.L2+4` is `i(GOT)`, it is the offset of varaibel `i` in `GOT`.

Look at the result of `objdump` is more intuitive.

```
00000450 <foo>:
 450:   4b03        ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; (460 <foo+0x10>)
 452:   4a04        ldr r2, [pc, #16]   ; (464 <foo+0x14>)
 454:   447b        add r3, pc
 456:   589b        ldr r3, [r3, r2]
 458:   681a        ldr r2, [r3, #0]
 45a:   6018        str r0, [r3, #0]
 45c:   4610        mov r0, r2
 45e:   4770        bx  lr
 460:   00008ba8    andeq   r8, r0, r8, lsr #23
 464:   0000001c    andeq   r0, r0, ip, lsl r0
 468:   f3af 8000   nop.w
 46c:   f3af 8000   nop.w
```

In the disassembly, `.L2` and `.L2+4` is replaced with specific offset. the result of `add    r3, pc` is `0x8ba8 + 0x458 = 0x9000`. Then `ldr    r3, [r3, r2]` would load from address `0x901c`. Look up these address in the section header:

```
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  ...
  [17] .got              PROGBITS        00009000 001000 000024 04  WA  0   0  4
  ...
```

the address `0x9000` is the entry of global offset table, and `0x901c` is also in this section. the symbol info of `0x901c` could be find in the `.rel.dyn` section:

```
Relocation section '.rel.dyn' at offset 0x348 contains 7 entries:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
...
00009018  00000415 R_ARM_GLOB_DAT    00000000   _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000901c  00000515 R_ARM_GLOB_DAT    00000000   i
00009020  00000615 R_ARM_GLOB_DAT    00000000   __cxa_finalize
```

Comment: at `add    r3, pc`,  `pc` shouldn't be `0x456` ?

Comment: No, 0x458 is correct. In ARM, the PC is always "ahead" by two instructions. That is 4 bytes for Thumb and 8 bytes for ARM.